# Numbers of way to solve quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many ways can a quadratic equation of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ be solved?

The most common one I know is the quadratic formula and factorization method.

$x=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4ac}}{2a}$

and $(ax+b)(cx+d)=0$

Comment: https://www.aplustopper.com/factorization-by-splitting-middle-term/

Comment: another alternative is by completing the square for those quadratics that don't factorise cleanly by inspection. generally though, the quadratic formula is the best way.

Comment: How do you solve the equation $x^2+3x+1=0$ through the “factorization method”?

Comment: The radicand must be $$b^2-4ac$$

Comment: You have printed the quadratic formula incorrectly,  More broadly, I'd expect that various methods that work in general end up being more or less equivalent to the quadratic formula.  Certainly, completing the squares is.  There are numerical methods of course...Newton's is quite effective for quadratics.  But these just approximate the relevant square root.